# Git - working on wrong branch - how to copy changes to existing topic branch

Tags: git

I've been working on a project, but unfortunately, I *forgot* to switch to my branch, and as such have been working on master

How can I copy the work (3 files) I've done here from master, to my branch (called, for example *branch123*) without comitting to master?

Answer (score 747, accepted):

Sounds like all you need is the following:

```
git stash
git checkout branch123
git stash apply
```

Then you should be back on your own branch without touching the master branch.

Comment: ok- i ran that, but when i switch back to master (git checkout master) and run git status, the same files are still "modified" - is that expected?

Comment: You may not actually have to stash, if the differences between your current branch (master) and the topic branch (branch123) are not in any of the files which you've modified locally. Git will let you simply check out the topic branch in that case.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, that's expected. This doesn't involve commits. `stash` saves away local modifications, then `stash apply` brings them back.

Comment: how can i "get rid" of them from the master branch.. to leave that clean?

Comment: `git stash` should not leave any "modified" files. When you say "modified", I take it you mean files tracked by git, i.e. that you have committed before? Untracked files, on the other hand, will be left out by `git stash`, and will appear as untracked no matter what branch you're currently on.

Comment: ok- they're tracked (been comitted before) - i modified them, then ran stash, as you said. applied the stash on branch123. comitted. Switched back to master, git status shows the files are still "modified" - how can i undo the modifications on the master branch?

Comment: `git reset --hard HEAD` and you're back to the last commit you made to your master branch.

Comment: This will also nuke all the changes which is not what he wants to do.

Comment: @boyfarrell Yes it is; the commit is still linked on his topic branch, and hence won't be lost.

Comment: fyi; if you stashed and then did a hard reset and found your changes disappeared. switch back to your target branch and do a `git stash apply` and they will be restaged

Comment: Might have already been said, but stashing will only work if you have not done a git add and/or git commit on your changes. If you've already committed your changes to the wrong branch you will have to reset back to the commit prior to starting your changes, do a reset "soft" so that all your changes stay, git checkout -b "newBranch", then commit your changes to that branch.

Comment: What, the stash is shared by all branches? All those years...

Answer (score 72):

The accepted answer is the most thorough, but there is a special case where you can simplify.  If the files you have modified in the working directory are identical in both `master` and `branch123` you can simply do

```
git checkout branch123
```

No need to stash anything, since the default behavior of `checkout` is to NOT overwrite modified files in your working directory, so you won't lose anything. (This was actually mentioned in the comments first by Cascabel)

As other people have mentioned in the comments, if `branch123` doesn't exist yet, you can do

```
git checkout -b branch123
```

Based on what I found [here](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/04/01/git-oops-i-changed-those-files-in-the-wrong-branch/).

Comment: Or, if you want to create a new branch, `git checkout -b newbranch`

Comment: This is working better for me than stash and it's much easier. Thanks!

Comment: No this doesnt work. Git will show you this message: "commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches."

Comment: @DegenSharew:  Yes, you are right in some cases, namely, if the files you have modified in the working directory are not identical in `master` and `branch123`.  See my edited answer.

Comment: This worked great for me. I didn't have a branch made yet, so I did this: git checkout -b newbranchname. My changes showed up in that branch on their own.

Comment: It's great, helped in my case (which seems identical to OP's one - 3 files, no commits, wrong branch)

Comment: This ONLY works if the differences between the branches are not in any of the files which you've modified locally. I would love to see an answer to this question that mentions that sometimes you don't need to stash end that sometimes you do need to stash.

Answer (score 6):

`git stash` is what you need.

a full explanation can be found in [Git-Tools-Stashing](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)

Answer (score 0):

As it is possible to create a new branch but not possible to checkout an existing branch while having files checked out, I found the following trick using a temporary branch to work:

This scenario works at least with VS 2015 Git plugin but would most likely work with any git tool.

1. checkout and make changes to files in master (ups!, wrong branch)
2. create a new branch "temp" (or any unused name you choose) from master. Checked out files will now be checked out in temp and not in master.
3. check in changes to temp (master is untouched)
4. Everything is now checked in and it is possible to check out an existing branch. Check out the wanted branch (the branch I wanted to make the changes to begin with)
   3.5 Git Rebase
5. merge temp to the wanted branch. Now the changes are in the correct branch.
6. delete the temp branch as it is not needed any more

EDIT: I found out that you will have to perform a rebase (git rebase --onto) of the temp branch before performing the merge. Otherwise the changes in master will be included in the merge. An extra step 3.5 above. See further about rebase here: 
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The solution is quite simple though and follows the same principle as the "stash" solution except that a temporary branch is used instead of the stash. This is more convenient at least for Visual Studio users since stash is not supported by the GIT plugin

Answer (score 0):

#### Github Desktop

In Github Desktop, when creating a new branch or moving to a different branch with uncommitted changes, you will be asked if you want to *leave* the changes or *move* them to the new branch:

[image]